# Change opacity of UIColor in SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've added a color asset with opacity and tried to use that in SwiftUI View like `.foregroundColor(Color("customAlertColor").opacity(0.3))` but setting opacity did not have any effect no matter what value I set it to.

[image]

Also I've tried to set Color using rgb values like `.foregroundColor(Color(.sRGB, red: 242/255, green: 242/255, blue: 242/255, opacity: 0.2))` but it also didn't help.

If I change the opacity of one of the system colors like `.foregroundColor(.blue.opacity(0.8))` that perfectly reflects the change.

Do I need to setup UIColor differently to get opacity working with the SwiftUI View?

Comment: On what view did you try to apply this? It works for me on a `Text`.

Comment: Why are you dividing by 255? Color channels aren’t 8-bit anymore.

Comment: @Jessy the argument labels take in [values from `0` to `1`](https://swiftontap.com/color/init(_:red:green:blue:opacity:))

Comment: @aheze The division operation isn’t the problem. Representing input as 0-255 is the problem, and the division just comes along for the ride in the hoopty.

Comment: @aheze no this is only for iOS lower than 10. **On applications linked for iOS 10 or later, the color is specified in an extended color space, and the input value is never clamped.** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init

Comment: @LeoDabus OP's using SwiftUI's `Color`, not `UIColor`

Comment: to reafirm what @Sweeper said, it works well on views such as Text. 
            .foregroundColor(Color("customAlertColor").opacity(0.6))
            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 49/255, green: 163/255, blue: 159/255).opacity(0.6))
            .foregroundColor(Color(.sRGB, red: 49/255, green: 163/255, blue: 159/255, opacity: 0.6))   The color is probably not the problem, show us a bit more code on how you use it.

Comment: @aheze never mind he is using sRGB so it is actually clamped.

Comment: @Sweeper @workingdog 
I'm using it on Rectangle.
`Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color("customAlertColor").opacity(0.3)`

Answer (score 1):

all works well for me with the following test code, on macos 11.4, xcode 12.5, target ios 14.5 and macCatalyst 11.3. I guess there must be some other code (or settings) that is impacting on the results. Is this test working for you?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(Color("customAlertColor").opacity(0.3))
          //  .foregroundColor(Color(red: 49/255, green: 163/255, blue: 159/255).opacity(0.3))
          //  .foregroundColor(Color(.sRGB, red: 49/255, green: 163/255, blue: 159/255, opacity: 0.3))
    }
}
```